# What are the advantages and disadvantages of hiding sub-levels of navigation ref. DIY.com?

Tags: navigation, information-architecture, mega-menu

I'm specifically referring to DIY.com here and I have not seen this type of navigation before (have you?)

My question(s) is(are) this: what are the reasons why [www.DIY.com](http://www.diy.com) have hidden some of their sub-levels of Navigation behind "view alls" upon rollover of primary category eg. garden? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this UI? (ie. in this example, there are actually 6 sub-categories under "Sheds and Storage" but they've decided to only show 3. Why? Is there any research to support the advantages of this?

I can take a good guess as to why this is the case (reduce level of cognition, reduce choice, promote certain sub-categories). A clear disadvantage being summarised by Jared Spool.

> Users can't predict the future, so they don't know they need to reveal
>   the menu to get what they need. - *Jared Spool*

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I would assume it is because it barely fits on screen as it is. If they were to show *all* categories in the nav then then the whole menu itself would be too big to fit on the screen. Jared's quote is less relevant here - It's not like it's one single 'menu' button; it's a 'View All' link underneath the Sheds & Storage category. I guess it could be slightly improved by renaming it 'View all Sheds & Storage' but the position of each 'View All' link already implies it's associated to the category headings. How would you design this menu to be better? They can't include *everything* in the menu.

Comment: Agreed, but don't you think there are other options and they've gone for this option for a reason. What is that reason? For example, they could have approached a [link](http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/) catch all approach? Or a more linear [link](http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/index.html) approach? Or even just link the user through to the category and show the user the subs there? Do you not think this approach seems to be taken from a design POV (i.e. all sub-category containers on the mega menu are 4 line height)? What do you think?

Comment: We're just going to be making assumptions as to *the* reason for this. Unless someone from the B&Q web development team who was actually involved in the build is a member of this site and can answer exactly.

Comment: Indeed, that's the whole premise of the question. We're assuming X / Y / Z. My question is (or should be maybe I need to rephrase it) based around is there any research to suggest that this method of navigation is / was the best choice /most converting for the end user?

Comment: Amazon and other big sites have a similiar menu if I'm not mistaken.  There is just limited screen space is what I think too.

Comment: I think they don't show it all because the function of the drop down mega-menu is to help users **preview** lower-level content in context.  There's no need for users to see all sub level, they just need to see most popular or top rated to get a sense of what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the logic behind this design is sound from an Information architecture point of view so you are right in pointing out that:

> I can take a good guess as to why this is the case (reduce level of
>   cognition, reduce choice, promote certain sub-categories).

I would add that the design follows a number of Information architecture principals :

**The Principle of Choices as outlined below :**

> The Paradox of Choice is a book by Barry Schwartz [1] that came out in
>   2005. In brief, the book’s message is that a greater number of options can make it more difficult for people to make a decision. More options
>   means more cognitive effort, and more effort can sometimes mean more
>   anxiety. People think they like having a lot of options, but they
>   really do not.

So your guess is spot-on, presenting the user with too many choices overwhelms the user and causes cognitive overload.

**The Principle of Exemplars as outlined below :**

> Describe the contents of categories by showing examples of the
>   contents.

You are also right on this one, by showing number of sub-categories the designer is showcasing examples of the products to improve user understanding of what this category includes.

**Last but not least: The Principle of Progressive Disclosure as outlined below :**

> Show only enough information to help people understand what kinds of
>   information they’ll find as they dig deeper.

By showing a limited number of products under each category the designer is setting users expectations of what they will find if they dig deeper while also providing a link to most visited sub-category pages.

With regard to "view all" link i think its part of the progressive disclosure approach as users are guided to take action once they have understood what each category includes.

I would end with this quote which sums up things quite well :

> Information presented to a person who is not interested or ready to
>   process it is effectively noise.